# Chrome apt repo returns 404

Tags: google-chrome

I've noticed my apt-get update command for Google Chrome has been failing for quite some time now and I'm not sure if it's an issue with my machine or if others have the same issue.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` contains:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main
```

But performing an `apt-get update` always fails on this repo.

Additionally, Google reports a 404 for the repo URL `https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb`.

Has Google changed the way Chrome is updated?

Comment: What is the exact error that `apt` gives on this repo? Have you tried re-installing Chrome by downloading the package again from [the official download page](https://www.google.com/chrome)? This should fix most problems. Also, it could be a problem with the repository keys missing from your system, please try adding them as mentioned [here](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/).

Comment: The repo has never been `https`.

Comment: changing the url to http still returns 404

Comment: Where do you change that url? It won't work in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bad idea to manually add this to the file.

If you install Chrome from a deb downloaded from Google, it adds the correct entry.

The wrong part is `https`. Change it to `http`, and all should work.

The correct entry, that is automatially set is:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

It works now.

Comment: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb is now reporting a 404 error

Comment: This link isn't supposed to be used in a browser. The repo works OK for me.

Comment: It was giving 404 error in apt update, but it works for me now. Maybe it was down earlier.